# Dividing a date range into equal chunks containing a set number of day chunks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to write a function but I'm drawing a blank trying to wrap my head around how to achieve my goal.

I am writing a wrapper for an API that filters data by a start date and an end date but will only let you request 90 days of data at a time and does not paginate data.

I would like to write a function that would take in a `startDate`, `endDate` and `maxDays` that would then split the date range down into smaller equal start and end chunks containing no more than the `maxDays` constraint.

The chunks should not overlap each-other but the original `startDate` and `endDate` should be preserved.

Edit: The function should return an array of objects. For example:

```js
[
  { start: "", end: "" },
  { start: "", end: "" },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Try the date api. You can create a Date object for the start date, then use the setDate() method to add the interval get the end date. If the resulting end date is after the targeted end date, break the loop and use the targeted end date. You're going to want to make sure the end date is after the start date, or you could trigger an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the start date and add *maxDays* to get the end of the block. If the block date is greater than the end date, use the end date instead. Then add *maxDays* to the start and go again until the start is `>=` than the end.

Copy dates before pushing into the array so don't affect original or ongoing processing.

```js
function getDateBlocks(start, end, maxDays) {
  let result = [];
  // Copy start so don't affect original
  let s = new Date(start);

  while (s < end) {
    // Create a new date for the block end that is s + maxDays
    let e = new Date(s.getFullYear(), s.getMonth(), s.getDate() + maxDays);
    // Push into an array. If block end is beyond end date, use a copy of end date
    result.push({start:new Date(s), end: e <= end? e : new Date(end)});
    // Increment s to the start of the next block which is one day after 
    // the current block end
    s.setDate(s.getDate() + maxDays + 1);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getDateBlocks(new Date(2021,0,1), new Date(2021,0,20), 6));
```

You need to work out if the dates are inclusive or not. In the above, 6 day blocks will go 1–7 Jan, 8–14 Jan, etc. If you want 1–6, 7–13, etc. subtract 1 from *maxDays* before doing the *while* loop.

You should also check that *maxDays* is a positive integer or the loop may be be infinite…

Answer (score 0):

Just keep adding days using [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) until you're past the end date:

```js
const chunk = (start, end, days) => {
  const result = [];
  const current = new Date(start.getTime());
 
  do {
    const d1 = new Date(current.getTime());
    const d2 = new Date(current.setDate(current.getDate() + days));
    
    result.push({
      start: d1,
      end: d2 <= end ? new Date(d2.setDate(d2.getDate() - 1)) : end
    });
  } while (current <= end);
  
  return result;
};

const chunks = chunk(
  new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 0, 1)),   // Jan 1, 2021
  new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 11, 31)), // Dec 31, 2021
  90                                // 90 days
);

console.log(chunks);
```

These types of methods are usually annoying to write in JavaScript due to the fact that `Date` objects are mutable and the date/time API is quite poor. I mostly work around that by only mutating the `Date` object named  `current` as I progress through the date intervals.