# Split Date Range based on Fortnight (till mid month)

Tags: javascript, date, split, logic

I have one requirement wherein i have to split the date range using Javascript based on fortnight but not getting any easy way for the same.

```
Start Date =  2 Dec
End Date =  16 Feb
```

So it will split as 6 rows

```
2dec - 15dec
16dec - 31dec
1jan - 15jan
16jan - 31jan
1feb - 15feb
16feb - 16feb
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*Dividing a date range into equal chunks containing a set number of day chunks in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004033/257182)

Comment: The result seems out of balance. 2 to 15 Dec is 14 days inclusive, 16 to 31 Dec is 16 days, 1 to 15 Jan is 15 days. What are you actually after?

Comment: It is not 14 days gap, but till mid of month (15th). The requirement is to filter based on half month.

Comment: You seem to just want start to 15th, 16th to end. Start is always 1st or earlier date, end is always 15th or days in month. There are plenty of questions about that. Write some code, if you have problems post it and ask for help.

Comment: Thanks, i can create custom js code and its working